# Can't download pictures from website using Python and requests

Tags: python, image, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm practicing my web scraping skills in Python. I want to download images from a real estate website [www.immobilier.ch](https://www.immobilier.ch/). I did it successfully with other websites, but this time when I want to save content of URL, after saving I see this inside a file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
</body></html>
```

Does anyone knows a way to avoid it? As I far as I understand this website identifies me as a bot. But weird that I can scrape everything else except for the pictures. I use Requests library for saving pictures, OS to save them in a right path and Selenium webdriver (Chrome). This is a sample of my code:

```
image_url = driver.find_element_by_class_name("im__col__content").find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute("src") #comment
path = "C:/Users/potek/Jupyter_projects/APARTMENTS"
with open(os.path.join(path, "Immobilier"+str(time.time())+".jpg"), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(i).content)
```

Comment: If my answer has solved your question, please accept it, otherwise leave a comment with more questions/details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using browser controllers like Selenium and Webbot the headers sent to the server would be valid and the server won't be able to identify you as a bot unless your traffic is much greater volume than would be expected, eg, if you have 100 drivers open all clicking 10 times per second on images/links etc.

BUT, for the request you send direct to the image URL, you're not using the browser wrapper, you're using basic requests which does not come with the headers for free. You have to manually set headers to make the server think the request has come from a legitimate browser, for example:

```py
header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'}
res = requests.get(url = 'https://www.immobilier.ch/Medias/bory-cie-agence-immobiliere-sa-21/641557/images/NewThumbnail/20445175.jpg', headers = header)
```

If the driver has a method to get the headers that are being used already then that would be a better solution as some server side request legitimacy checking compares the number of different browser headers received from a certain IP address and temporarily blocks those as well. If you want to scrape a LOT of data for a long time, cycling through a dozen or so free proxy IP addresses such as from https://free-proxy-list.net/uk-proxy.html as well as a dozen or so headers would also help keep you undetected.

Comment: Thank you @G.S 
I tried using free-proxy, unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.
But headers on the other hand worked exactly the way I wanted.
Thank you so much for your clarification regarding my problem =)